# Rails partials not generating docx using Caracal gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, docx

I'm trying to generate .docx file via the caracal gem (https://github.com/trade-informatics/caracal). It's wrapped with their rails gem - caracal-rails.

I tried using partials in `show.docx.caracal` file with `render partial: 'template'` pointing to `_template.docx.caracal` file. There was no error, but content of partial was no included in generated document. There were only `docx.p`s from `show` and no `docx.p`s from partial.

If anybody using this gem tried partials - is there a way to use partials with this gem? (maybe it's not working because tilt which caracal uses has no compiler for these type of files?)